# Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:6935', transport: 'socket'

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot

I create new spring boot project with java 12.
when i run the project or debug it say me

```
Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:6935', transport: 'socket'
```

Its my main method

```
package shc.api;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class ApiApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ApiApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

And its my pom file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.5.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>SHC</groupId>
    <artifactId>api</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>api</name>
    <description>REST API</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>12</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>


      <!-- my other module -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>SHC</groupId>
            <artifactId>command</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>

  <!-- my other module -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>SHC</groupId>
            <artifactId>domain</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.persistence-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.7.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>

    </build>

</project>
```

Befor its work fine.

I dont know the problem reason.

its problem drive me crazy .

I dont know the tomcat cause it or default  spring boot config cause it.

But the port number every time will change .

Comment: How have you created this project? It's a mix and not a real Spring Boot Project. To create a spring boot project go to: https://start.spring.io/